# SQL; Search by merged column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm creating a stored procedure. I have 2 columns, forename and surname.

I'm able to merge them using this statement:

```
REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Forename, ' ', '') + ' ' + 
     REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Surname, ' ', '') AS EmployeeFullName
```

If I wanted to search by the `EmployeeFullName`, how would I do that?

```
WHERE EmployeeFullName = @Name
```

where `@name` would be the parameter input for the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeSearch
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SELECT 
        dbo.Employee.Number, 
        REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Forename, ' ', '') + ' ' + REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Surname, ' ', '') AS EmployeeFullName, 
        DateOfBirth
    FROM 
        dbo.Employee
    WHERE        
        EmployeeFullName = @Name

    RETURN
GO
```

Comment: What is the format of `@Name` values?

Comment: @Dai I've updated the question to include the format.

Comment: You specified the type, but not the format of the values. Is it just a single name component, or a full name, a partial match. If someone searches for "Bob Dole" should it also return "Robert Dole" too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the stored procedure like below :

```
CREATE procedure EmployeeSearch 
@name varchar(50)
as
begin

    SELECT Number, EmployeeFullName from (
        SELECT dbo.Employee.Number, REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Forename, ' ', '') + ' ' + REPLACE(dbo.Employee.Surname, ' ', '') AS EmployeeFullName
        FROM yourtable
    ) AS T WHERE EmployeeFullName = @Name

end
```

Comment: What about the other values I'm returning?

Comment: Thank You :) This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A predicate (`WHERE` clause) based on function results is typically non-Sargable which means the database cannot use indexes to quickly find results - so if you have a large table then it will run slowly.

I recommend searching by name components in your application layer, not in your SQL code. (BTW if your Stored Procedure is only performing read operations (i.e. only `SELECT`, and no `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` operations) then you should use a Table-valued function instead of a Stored Procedure.

i.e. have a parameter for each name component.